# Angular digest - TypeError: v12 is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if, angularjs-digest

I'm using AngularJs 1 in a project. I've noticed that sometimes I get the error

```
TypeError: v12 is not a function. (In 'v12(v16)', 'v12' is false)
fn
$digest — angular.js:18363
$apply — angular.js:18640
done — angular.js:12618
completeRequest — angular.js:12862
requestLoaded — angular.js:12779
undefined
(funzione anonima) — angular.js:11209
(funzione anonima) — angulartics.js:425
$digest — angular.js:18389
$apply — angular.js:18640
done — angular.js:12618
completeRequest — angular.js:12862
requestLoaded — angular.js:12779
angular.js:11209
```

in the console and I don't understand what it is related to.

---

I don't know if it's related, but some `ng-if` don't work (just some).

It's strange because the code

```
<div ng-if="isAdmin">Am I Admin? {{isAdmin}}</div>
```

shows

```
Am I Admin? false
```

---

### Further details

That code is contained in a template of a custom directive

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {   return {
    replace    : true,
    restrict   : 'E',
    scope      :
      {
          /* -------
           &    : function
           @    : 1-way
           =    : 2-ways
          ---------*/
          isAdmin          : '@'
```

used as follow

```
<my-directive  is-admin="{{ctrl.isAdmin}}">
</my-directive>
```

Comment: You just have Javascript error and thats why Angular wont render ngIf correctly... You should first check if you have this error in non-minified code.

Comment: actually, it’s not minified

Comment: it's very hard to find the problem without any reference to the variable/line ...  what error could generate this error message? I've never seen it

Comment: can you put your code on plunker so we can check it.

Comment: solved,  thank you. I wrote the answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's wrong, it's the symbol used in parameters passed to the directive.

I used

```
// directive spec
.directive('myDirective', function() {   return {
    scope      :
      {  isAdmin : '@' }

// directive usage
<my-directive  is-admin="{{ctrl.isAdmin}}">
</my-directive>
```

but the correct way is

```
// directive spec
.directive('myDirective', function() {   return {
    scope      :
      {  isAdmin : '=' }

// directive usage
<my-directive  is-admin="ctrl.isAdmin">
</my-directive>
```

Since `@` it's 1 way, while `=` is 2 ways. So I guess using `@` the boolean values are converted into a string. With `=` everything works. By the way I really don't know why I got that weird error `TypeError: v12 is not a function. (In 'v12(v16)', 'v12' is false)`